# MYSQL error and not null still adding data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a piece of code I am trying to use to populate a new database table.  The problem I am having is that i am getting the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'N TENSION')' at line 2

The second problem is that the code inserts all entries and not just the ones where the field search_term has a value

my code is here

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM vistordetails1 WHERE search_term IS NOT NULL";      
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$search_term =$row['search_term'];
    $client_id =$row['client_id'];


     mysql_query("INSERT INTO google1 
     (client_id, term) VALUES('$client_id', '$search_term') ") 
                   or die(mysql_error());  

          }
```

Comment: where is the query that has `N TENSION`?

Comment: Sorry it would relate to the insert Search term variable

Comment: The old mysql extension is depreciated. Consider using PDO or the mysqli extension instead.

Comment: Please update your question to show the values of `$client_id` and `$search_term`, or post the entire query.

Comment: The second problem might simply be cause by the fact that the search term is an empty string in the cases you want to skip. An empty string is different from IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Thanks That is the whole query minus the db connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything with a single query:

```
INSERT INTO google1 (client_id, term)
SELECT client_id, search_term
FROM vistordetails1
WHERE search_term IS NOT NULL
      AND search_term <> ''
```

(anyway, the problem is that probably you have a term that contains a `'`, and it is not correctly escaped)